# Importing time-dependent mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, import

I have recently found that Mathematica (a mathematics software) may export .stl files, which may be used for Blender. This is very good for me because I am interested in mathematics visualization, and this team Mathematica-Blender seems to be most convenient for this purpose. However, I suppose that when working with animations, I will need curves or surfaces which move according to mathematic equations. See for example the figures in the following video:

[Film *Dimensions*, Chapter 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eef3twD0N94)

It is extremely easy to export *just one mesh*, allowing me to use Blender for mathematics pictures. But for animations, since Blender does not seem to support high mathematics, it would be great to export somehow a time-dependent mesh. Is there something like this available? More concretely, focusing on the Blender problem (and not in Mathematica), is there any file type from which Blender may import a time dependent mesh?

Any idea or suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: What are you defining a time-dependent mesh as? A sequence of individual meshes?

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes, but all merged into a single document, more or less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the NewTek MDD and PC2 formats (though you may have to enable their separate addons in the user preferences to get those import/export formats to appear).

This can be used in conjunction with the '[Mesh Cache'](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/mesh_cache.html) modifier to play back a sequence of external meshes:

[image]

There also appears to be a script to import .obj sequences as well, which tends to be a more common format, found [here at BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252844-Script-Meshfoot-OBJ-Sequence-Manager-%28For-Blender-2.6.2%29), but I am not  sure of any potential limitations it may have.