# Huge size for gltf imported file

Tags: shape-keys

I have a sequence of objs and I have converted them to glTF. To do so, I have a glTF mesh and a morph target for each of the objs in the sequence. I also have an animation to switch from one morph target to another. This glTF file occupies 65 MB, but when I imported into blender, the .blend file occupies 1.1GB and its really difficult to work with it as its not responding well.

The blend file basically consist on a mesh, 4k shapekeys for that mesh (which represent the obj sequence) and an animation for each one of the shapekeys values.

Is it normal that something like that use so much space and its so unresponsive?

Comment: Something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23349/importing-time-dependent-mesh and have the shapekeys cached outside the blend?. Old link there's prob newer.

Comment: To add some more info, even when all the shapekeys are muted, its slow

Comment: Your solution works, but its still a bit uncomfortable. I am loading the glTF file which has all the shapekeys, then export the object as an mdd. Then remove the shapekeys and load the mdd in the Cache Mesh modifier. Since I have a python script which generates the glTF file, it would be nice to generate directly the mdd. However I can't find the specs for it. Do you know where I can get them?